# Generate math symbols from argument

Tags: math-mode, macros, math-operators, arguments

I have been trying to create a small latex math symbol reference. My list will require repetition of lines like `\textbackslash lfloor - $\lfloor$`. I want to create a command that takes in one argument that is either the symbol name `lfloor` or the command itself `\lfloor`. But in either scenario, I have trouble showing the other case. How can I define such command?

Comment: see the source of other math symbol lists eg https://ctan.org/pkg/maths-symbols  basically `\def\foo#1{\texttt{\string#1} $#1$} ...\foo\rightarrow`

Comment: Look up \verb.  The first and last characters after it are used as delimiters and not displayed.  e.g \verb|\lfloor|

Comment: The command you are looking for is ``\string``. 
Nevertheless, the approach suggested by  David Carlisle in the reference he quote, tough based on ``\string``,  is ore powerfull in the sense that it avoid to repeat the command to be illustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is only about single control sequence tokens and if  eTeX-extensions are available, you can probably use a combination of `\string`, `\scantokens` and the `\verb`-command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\myCsPrintCommand[1]{%
  \expandafter\InnermyCsPrintCommand\expandafter{\string#1}%
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\?=14\relax
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\@firstofone{?
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\InnermyCsPrintCommand[1]{?
    \scantokens\expandafter{\string\verb|#1| -- $#1$%}?
  }?
}%
% The trickery above is needed for bringing a %-char/comment-char
% into \scantokens' argument. That in turn is needed for neutralizing
% the endline-character inserted at the end of \scantokens' argument.

\begin{document}
\myCsPrintCommand{\lfloor} 
\myCsPrintCommand{\rfloor}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion this is sort of overkill, but I nonetheless decided to show the underlying `\scantokens`-trickery as it can be used not only with `\verb` but with other commands also whose arguments usually should not be delivered via macros but via reading and tokenizing input as these arguments should be read/tokenized under different catcode-régime, e.g.  `\lstinline` from the listings-package, or whatever else is to be used for pretty-printing the control words.

Nonetheless the following example is my attempt at providing a generic macro `\myCsPrintCommand` which lets you format the pretty-printing of a control sequence with commands like `\verb` or `\lstinline` as well:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color, listings}

%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Both pretty-print a control sequence and typeset the result 
%% from carrying out the control sequence:
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \myCsPrintCommand{<stringified-printing-command>}%
%%                  {<verb-delimiter>}%
%%                  {<separator>}%
%%                  {<formatting-when-carrying-out-command>}%
%%                  {<control sequence to typeset>}%
%%
%% ->
%% either
%%   <stringified-printing-command><verb-delimiter><control sequence to typeset><verb-delimiter>%
%%   <separator><formatting-when-carrying-out-command>{<control sequence to typeset>}
%% or
%%   <stringified-printing-command>{<control sequence to typeset>}%
%%   <separator><formatting-when-carrying-out-command>{<control sequence to typeset>}
%%
%% <stringified-printing-command> prints the character-sequence that
%% forms the control sequence.
%% <stringified-printing-command> either can be something with \verb-syntax -
%% in this case you need to specify a <verb-delimiter>, e.g., |, or
%% can be something that does process one undelimited argument -
%% in this case you need to leave the <verb-delimiter>-argument empty.
%% 
%% <formatting-when-carrying-out-command> influences how the result from
%% carrying out <control sequence to typeset> gets typeset.
%% <formatting-when-carrying-out-command> can be a control sequence that
%% processes one undelimited argument.
%%
%% e.g., \myCsPrintCommand{\verb}{|}{--}{\textbf}{\LaTeX}
%%       -> \verb|\LaTeX|--\textbf{\LaTeX}
%% e.g., \myCsPrintCommand{\verb}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\lfloor}
%%       -> \verb|\lfloor| -- \ensuremath{\lfloor}
%% e.g., \myCsPrintCommand{\myownstringifier}{}{--}{\ensuremath}{\lfloor}
%%       -> \myownstringifier{\lfloor}--\ensuremath{\lfloor}
%% 
\newcommand\myCsPrintCommand[5]{%
  \expandafter\InnermyCsPrintCommand\expandafter{\string#5}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}%
}%
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\catcode`\?=14\relax
\catcode`\%=12\relax
\@firstofone{?
  \endgroup
  ??----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ?? Expandably within two expansion steps check whether argument is empty:
  ??----------------------------------------------------------------------
  ?? \UDCheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
  ??                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  ??                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
  ??                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
  ??                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
  ??
  ?? The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
  ?? <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
  ??......................................................................
  \newcommand\UDCheckWhetherNull[1]{?
    \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
    \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}?
    \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}?
  }?
  \newcommand\InnermyCsPrintCommand[5]{?
    \UDCheckWhetherNull{#3}{?
      \scantokens\expandafter{\string#2{#1}#4#5{#1}%}?
    }{?
     \scantokens\expandafter{\string#2#3#1#3#4#5{#1}%}?
    }?
  }?
}%
% The trickery above is needed for bringing a %-char/comment-char
% into \scantokens' argument. That in turn is needed for neutralizing
% the endline-character inserted at the end of \scantokens' argument.

\begin{document}

%% \myCsPrintCommand{<stringified-printing-command>}%
%%                  {<verb-delimiter>}%
%%                  {<separator>}%
%%                  {<formatting-when-carrying-out-command>}%
%%                  {<control sequence to typeset>}%

Example with \verb|\verb|:

\myCsPrintCommand{\verb}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\lfloor} 

\myCsPrintCommand{\verb}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\rfloor}

Example with \verb|\lstinline|:

\myCsPrintCommand{\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\lfloor} 

\myCsPrintCommand{\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\rfloor}

Example with \verb|\mybluestringified|:

\newcommand\mybluestringified[1]{%
  \textcolor{blue}{\texttt{\string#1}}%
}%

\myCsPrintCommand{\mybluestringified}{}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\lfloor} 

\myCsPrintCommand{\mybluestringified}{}{ -- }{\ensuremath}{\rfloor}

% You can put the call to \myCsPrintCommand into a macro:

\newcommand\printitwithverb{%
  \myCsPrintCommand{\verb}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}%
}%
\newcommand\printitwithlstinline{%
  \myCsPrintCommand{\lstinline[language={[LaTeX]TeX}]}{|}{ -- }{\ensuremath}%
}%
\newcommand\printitwithmybluestringified{%
  \myCsPrintCommand{\mybluestringified}{}{ -- }{\ensuremath}%
}%

Example with \verb|\printitwithverb|:

\printitwithverb{\lfloor} 

\printitwithverb{\rfloor}

Example with \verb|\printitwithlstinline|:

\printitwithlstinline{\lfloor} 

\printitwithlstinline{\rfloor}

Example with \verb|\printitwithmybluestringified|:

\printitwithmybluestringified{\lfloor} 

\printitwithmybluestringified{\rfloor}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If it's a single token `\newcommand*\csprintcmd[1]{\texttt{\string#1} -- $#1$}` is enough, no need for `\verb`.

Comment: @jfbu I use a group only at defining-time of the user-macros, not at the time of carrying out the user-macros. Your suggestion requires an assignment to `\endlinechar` and thus a local scope whenever the user-macros are used.

Comment: @Manuel As I already wrote within the answer: In my opinion the thing is sort of overkill. But it is a way of accomplishing things in case one wishes to use something for "pretty-printing" that does require a different catcode-régime, e.g., `\verb` or `\lstinline` or whatever. Of course with `\verb` this is somewhat  pointless/redundant as `\verb`'s `\verbatim@font` denotes `\ttfamily` as does `\texttt`. But there are packages that offer different/more sophisticated pretty-printing commands, e.g., with nice coloring of phrases, also requiring different catcode-régime for reading arguments.

Comment: yes your group is only for macro def (sorry for not looking too closely, but I felt the whole thing a bit overkill anyhow as you say elsewhere). I will delete my comment. As alternative to `\endlinechar` one can add a `\relax`: ``-- $#1$\relax}``  which will inhibit the trailing space (or `\empty`...)

Comment: for the fun, one can do this in one macro ``\expandafter\verb\scantokens\expandafter{\expandafter|\string#1|\relax}--$#1$``, the problem solved being with extra spaces when doing `\scantokens` (which is like writing to a file unexpanded, hence with spaces after control words and back). If one really really is not happy enough with `\string` `:)`

Comment: I hereby learn about `\scantokens` ability to create a pristine status for catcodes, I did not know about this "unfreezing" capability. For novices: `\verb` acts by making active the character following it immediately; here in my previous comment we have the scantokens acting before `\verb` and I usually interpret that as giving the current catcodes to the argument, but there is more to that because the catcode of the closing `|` can still be make active by `\verb`. This is surprising, but perhaps not so much if we think "writing to file, reading from file".

Comment: I had always considered `\scantokens` as setting the catcodes to what they are in surrounds, but this example shows it is not that, it is resetting a pristine state for catcodes assignments. (like when reading from file). Example ``\def\FOU{\scantokens{\catcode`+ 3 +a^2b^2+}}`` then execute ``\FOO``.

Comment: @jfbu Your `\expandafter\verb\scantokens`-thingie is cool as one doesn't need to stringify the control sequence `\verb`, which needs to be done when putting `\verb` inside `\scantokens`' `<balanced text>` for preventing the coming into being of a space right behind the `\verb`-control-sequence which then erroneously would be considered the `\verb`-delimiter.